# Why won't this work (C# - Web Browser Control)

Tags: c#-4.0

I have the following code to set a text to a input box:

```
private void messageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
                doc.GetElementsByTagName("input")
                    .GetElementsByName("message_id")
                    [0].SetAttribute("value", "Whats up");
            }
```

This is the info on that input box

```
<!-- Quick Message -->
        <br />
        <div id="quick-message">
            <form action="sendmessage.aspx" method="post" name="sendmessage">

            <input type="hidden" name="7e27a05c" value="369dd5604f64ea23be41fe37ac416276" />
            <input type="hidden" name="sguid" value="DECBD1FF570BA8D09B642734AA677B8731ABD318F67AF409519BEE228762D38CD62B6F2051F36ADAF50861146F83036C2294FC948945A200DEAE9D6C7A70FA795573066C96A8124F9FD18EB3B8D4C1B983BA81C426D644C6716C067C29FA917943115D5726F7AEFEC7E88C16F8F1FFA78B6A881F37EEA61B8475D148D5CB1D9797495F380612D0D35782C32333526C4D2FE047AD1A8044D808E07C18D190999561A68C205546363F3B624FDB40F65F54187FC89C6327918A3FE595F152C0FD41433C4FB07F0CD69EDB3BE615AE08A48A"/>

            <input type="hidden" name="autologinid" value="ayxwntt5met1yv0o0o0i5ctj" />
            <input type="hidden" name="message_id" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="u" value="3FF3XX" />

            <input type="hidden" value="44696155" name="p_id" />

            <input type="hidden" name="reciever" value="sarita_j" />
            <input type="hidden" value="44696155" name="profile_idb" />
            <input type="hidden" value="48936882" name="usersendtob" />
            <input type="hidden" name="i" value="59181062" />
            <input type="hidden" name="v" value="13" />
            <center>
                <span class="headline txtBlue size16">Send a Quick Message!</span>
                <input maxlength="40" name="subject" size="33" type="hidden" value="Hi" />
                <center>
                    <textarea class="profile" name="message"></textarea><br />
                    <input type="submit" class="button norm-green" style="" value="Send Quick Msg" name="sendmessage" /></center>
            </form>
```

However, when I click the button nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you doing a postback?  Your code is server-side; without a postback, the goggles will do nothing.

Comment: well I wana add the text to the box on button click automatically so after that I click Send a quick message.... @RobertHarvey

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think this is ASP.NET, it seems like he's trying to change a document displayed in an embedded browser in a desktop app. (That said, this is about 80% guessing, 20% assuming because it doesn't make sense to use a `WebBrowser` in ASP.NET)

Comment: The usual: have you tried using a debugger to see if your click handler gets called at all after clicking the button? And if it does, stepping through it and inspecting stuff to see where it could've gone wrong? (Also, you should consider tagging your question with the specific technologies you're using for what. .NET is a largish beast and it's not necessarily obvious from code snippets what you're actually doing.)

Comment: @millimoose the thing is nothing happens I don't even get an error

Comment: @user2309648 If nothing is happening (the `blah_Click()` method doesn't even get called), then the problem is in wiring of the click event, which isn't in the code you posted. That said, "nothing is happening" isn't really specific enough, since there's a few possible reasons why no apparent change would occur. It's up to you to pinpoint where things go wrong.

Comment: @millimoose I put a messagebox.show in there just to make sure the method is called and the message box poped up

Comment: @user2309648 Why haven't you started this in a debugger yet? Poke around the expressions in that method to see if they all have the values you believe should have.

Comment: @millimoose can you please assist me. I'm new with debugging

Comment: @user2309648 I can't reasonably teach you how to use your IDE over the internet. (Also I kind of don't want to.) Push buttons, see what they do, [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt(v=vs.110).aspx) when desperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not traverse the DOM like:

```
    HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
    foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
    {

        if ( elem.GetAttribute("name")=="message_id")
        {
          elem.SetAttribute("value","what's up");
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ Edper : How would I get the text from inside the text box would that be innertext or outertext?

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("extacy");
            HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(elem.InnerText);
                MessageBox.Show(elem.OuterText);
            }
        }

Comment: @user2309648 Sorry for this late reply. Since it is the value of the textbox and not the elements and inner text/html per se then you could use elem.GetAttribute("value") instead. You use innerHtml or innerText (has difference by the way) if you want the value between a pair of tag let's say <h1>The Heading</h1> which will give you the value "The Heading" (without the quote).

Comment: @ Edper: Thanks for the help .. When I enter some text ie: Hello World in the message box and use the getattribute method it doesn't show the hello world in message box .. code im using is :

HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(elem.GetAttribute("value"));
            }

Comment: You need to put ToString method after GetAttribute like MessageBox.Show(elem.GetAttribute("value").ToString());